# How to keep url from changing to another url but having the website change?

Tags: dns

I'm trying to make an html that is my website then goes to an established website but stays on the same page so that it doesn't get blocked. I don't want the URL to change from my google drive sharing site but I want it to be the other website. For example right now my "website" is just a hyperlink that opens Pinterest but it changes the url. How do I keep it as the original URL so it doesn't get blocked by my company. Should I use a different program to write it. Right now I'm using notepad, should I switch over to javascript or something else?

I tried looking up the answer and I don't think I got it. I am an amateur.